# How can the Magento caches & logs be cleared?

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, log

How can I go about clearing all of Magento's caches and logs by running a PHP script?

Comment: See link may very help full for clear cache and log http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133807/how-to-cache-and-log-table-clear-in-magento-1-9-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this old script](https://snipplr.com/view/56618/magento-php-file-and-database-maintenance) from 2011, create a file called cleanup.php and add the following code to it:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['clean']) {
    case 'log':
        clean_log_tables();
    break;
    case 'var':
        clean_var_directory();
    break;
}

function clean_log_tables() {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('./app/etc/local.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    
    if(is_object($xml)) {
        $db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
        $db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
        $db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
        $db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
        $db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;
        
        $tables = array(
            'adminnotification_inbox',
            'aw_core_logger',
            'dataflow_batch_export',
            'dataflow_batch_import',
            'log_customer',
            'log_quote',
            'log_summary',
            'log_summary_type',
            'log_url',
            'log_url_info',
            'log_visitor',
            'log_visitor_info',
            'log_visitor_online',
            'index_event',
            'report_event',
            'report_viewed_product_index',
            'report_compared_product_index',
            'catalog_compare_item',
            'catalogindex_aggregation',
            'catalogindex_aggregation_tag',
            'catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag'
        );
        
        mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());
        
        foreach($tables as $table) {
            @mysql_query('TRUNCATE `'.$db['pref'].$table.'`');
        }
    } else {
        exit('Unable to load local.xml file');
    }
}

function clean_var_directory() {
    $dirs = array(
        'downloader/.cache/',
        'downloader/pearlib/cache/*',
        'downloader/pearlib/download/*',
        'var/cache/',
        'var/locks/',
        'var/log/',
        'var/report/',
        'var/session/',
        'var/tmp/'
    );
    
    foreach($dirs as $dir) {
        exec('rm -rf '.$dir);
    }
}
```

Save the file to the magento root directory.

Run the following url For Log clearing

http://www.domain.com/cleanup.php?clean=log

Run the following url for Cache clearing

http://www.domain.com/cleanup.php?clean=var

Comment: You shouldn't truncate the table `log_summary_type`

Answer (score 6):

You're best of doing this from the command line using a SSH terminal or a cronjob

```
# rm -Rf /home/domain.com/www/var/cache/*
# rm -Rf /home/domain.com/www/var/log/*
```

This will be more reliable than using PHP

Comment: why should log be cleared unless its necessary. Aren't they useful to sort out error ?

Comment: they are but OP asked for a way to delete the log files so that's what I gave. :)

Comment: ohh sorry.. i didn't noticed the log files question :)

Comment: No problem. But you're right. It would be better to make a bash script that packs the log files every day and renames them by date so you have backups. Optionally delete those when they're older than X days

Comment: its a great idea... i have created a script for downloading and deleting log file monthly.

Answer (score 3):

- For clean log, shell script already exist in path-to-magento/shell directory:

  ```
  php log.php 
  Usage:  php -f log.php -- [options]
          php -f log.php -- clean --days 1

    clean             Clean Logs
    --days      Save log, days. (Minimum 1 day, if defined - ignoring system value)
    status            Display statistics per log tables
    help              This help
  ```
- For clean cache, following methods will help you to make a shell script:

  ```
  // Clean js and css
  Mage::getModel('core/design_package')->cleanMergedJsCss();
  Mage::dispatchEvent('clean_media_cache_after');

  // product image
  Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache();
  Mage::dispatchEvent('clean_catalog_images_cache_after');

  // Get cache types
  Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes()

  // Clean specific tags
  Mage::app()->cleanCache($tags);

  // dispatch event if you flush all cache tags
  Mage::app()->cleanCache($alltags);
  Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_flush_system');
  ```

Comment: I prefer an answer along these lines because it doesn't assume that the file cache is the one being used. There's also database, memcached, etc. which won't be cleared by emptying the `var/cache` folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the following from php.

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

Comment: This is pretty cool technique. Do i run this in terminal after starting php -a???? or do i create a file an add this into the file and then just visit the particular page??  @David Manners

Comment: you could create your own magento shell script that does this. Or you could consider using n98-magerun

Answer (score 1):

Goto system->Cache Management->Flush Magento Cache from admin panel OR clear var/cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, first you try to find the tables with most rows & size by using SQL:

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS "Table",
  TABLE_ROWS AS "Rows #",
  ROUND(
    (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024,
    2
  ) AS "Size (MB)"
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database-name'
  AND (
    TABLE_NAME LIKE 'log_%'
    OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'report_%'
    OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'dataflow_%'
    OR TABLE_NAME = 'catalog_compare_item'
  )
ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC
```

And you can run the truncate operation on the log tables.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
```

For more, please visit: https://blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-find-the-size-rows-of-magento-database-tables/